# Authorize.Net hosted form: how to verify payment succeeded after redirect

Tags: authorize.net

I'm using the hosted payment form with `getHostedPaymentPageRequest`

After successful payment the browser opens by success url correctly.

However, i dont know how to verify that payment was actually completed. I have the token from `getHostedPaymentPageRequest`, but i cant find an API to call to get the result of that transaction.

I can see that when using an IFrame we can use the `IFrameCommunicator`, but we would prefer to not use that.

How can i verify the transaction succeeeded after redirect back from the hosted payment page?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the iframe you won't get the results of the transaction in real time. Your best option then is to use a webhook to receive a notification of the successful payment. You can then get the transaction info using the transaction ID provided by the webhook. But that would mean the user won't know the status of their payment when they arrive back at your site. For that to happen you'd have to build a mechanism that does the above and have your receipt page poll your backend until it has the results of the transaction and then can display them to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its a shame authorize.net doesnt just give us the transid in a request param.